# How to bind amount of items on the list to a Label.Content property

Tags: c#, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I'm making a simple project in Silverlight. It contains a ListBox and a Label.
I tried to bind listbox.Items.Count property to Label.Content property so I can see amount of items which are currently present on it. I've used [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) as a support and information source.

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("CountProperty");
// columnNameList - listbox
myBinding.Source = this.columnNamesList.Items.Count;
// columnCount - label
this.columnCount.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, myBinding);
```

It does not work for some reason. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write

```
var myBinding = new Binding("Count");  // no "Property" suffix
myBinding.Source = this.columnNamesList.Items; // object that has the property "Count"
```

First off, the name of the property in the example you cite is actually supposed to include the suffix "Property". In this case the name of the property is simply "Count", so you have to make the binding reflect that.

Second, the binding source always is the object that exposes the property with that name. In your initial code, `this.columnNamesList.Items.Count` evaluates to the value of the property itself, not the object that exposes it.

Comment: Okey it helped and its working now. Could you care to write shortly why did you bind this.columnNamesList.Items as source instead of this.columnNamesList.Items.Count ? Thanks for help.

Comment: @neurotix: Because it is the list (".Items") that has the property named `Count`, while `Items.Count` is the value of the property. What I 'm saying in the last paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the information. I had written this before you expanded your answer.